# Was this spherical device used in weather forecasting in the 1960's?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

The New York Times obituary [Robert M. White, Who Revolutionized Weather Forecasts, Dies at 92](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/23/science/earth/robert-m-white-meteorologist-who-revolutionized-weather-forecasts-dies-at-92.html) shows the image below. It looks like it might be a model of the Earth but I can't tell for sure.

Can the sphere be identified, and if so, is it related to weather forecasting?

[image: Robert White in 1967]

click for full size

> Robert White in 1967. He led the federal government’s weather agencies through five presidencies in the 1960s and ’70s.Credit...Francis Miller/The LIFE Picture Collection/Getty Images

---

> Robert M. White, a meteorologist who revolutionized the nation’s weather forecasting system, **was the first to lead the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration and warned of climate change long before it was widely recognized**, died on Oct. 14 (2015) at his home in Chevy Chase, Md. He was 92.
>
> [...] **As the chairman of the First World Climate Conference in 1979, Dr. White gave a keynote speech that projected the possible consequences of human-induced warming of the planet. The speech, Dr. Baker said, was a turning point in the effort to promote global awareness of climate change.**

Comment: The cables/wire emanating from the south pole, going through the interior of the sphere & exiting at various angles from the non-transparent northern hemisphere are intriguing. Also, why is the southern hemisphere transparent, but not the northern hemisphere? ... mmm